# How to recover Ubuntu14.04 and Windows7 partition

Tags: partitioning

I used EaseUS Partition Master to make a new partition under windows7 for games. I made the new partition succesfully, but my computer can't find any bootable partition(grub rescue). Ubuntu's installer and gparted can't see the partitions, however disk utility see (under live cd) all the partitions and i can access them. How can i recover them with(out) data loss?

Comment: You need to give more details.  For starters, write out a table listing the partitions, their numbers, and types.  Then, look up the GRUB repair guides on the Ubuntu wiki.

Comment: That's right sorry. I made a screen shot for another site (ubuntu.hu): http://kepfeltoltes.hu/140428/Screenshot_from_2014-04-28_04_27_18_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png

Comment: I boot from live cd, but i couldn't use boot repair, because there wasn't an available internet connection in my school (mac address filtering), but anyway i solved it with a little data loss. I could only  edit the Ubuntu 14.04's partition from there, so i did it. After that the installer was able to read the partition table and install Ubuntu. So I deleted the partition and i installed Ubuntu to the new free space on the hard disk. The data loss was minimal, because i stored almost everything on windows7's partition and i made a backup before i made a new partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going on the information provided I'd suggest that you use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to fix this issue